# OAuth in Grafana with Windows Authentication over IIS, Blazor App

Tags: c#, iis, oauth, blazor, grafana

Good Day,

I am struggling with implementing the OAuth in a hosted NET-Application over IIS.
The main reason it is not working is because of the Windows Authentication, which I use for my NET-App over IIS.
When I turn on Anonymous Authentication everything works fine and I get redirected to my Dashboard, with the user I authenticate in my NET-App (Blazor Server).
But as soon as I turn Anonymous Authentication OFF in IIS, it will not work with anymore.

Is it possible to get it to work with Windows Authentication only? Do I need a specific configuration in web.config is the published App for that?

I am using Grafana 9.1.3, IIS 10, Firefox 104.0.2 and .NET 6.0 Blazor.

These are the changes in my custom.ini-File:

```
############## Server #################
[server]
# Protocol (http, https, h2, socket)
protocol = http

# The http port  to use
http_port = 3010

# The public facing domain name used to access grafana from a browser
domain = localhost

# The full public facing url you use in browser, used for redirects and emails
# If you use reverse proxy and sub path specify full url (with sub path)
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana

# Serve Grafana from subpath specified in `root_url` setting. By default it is set to `false` for compatibility reasons.
serve_from_sub_path = true

############# Generic OAuth ############
[auth.generic_oauth]
enabled = true
name = OAuth
allow_sign_up = true
client_id = postman
client_secret = postman-secret2
scopes = api openid
empty_scopes = false
email_attribute_name = 
;email_attribute_name = email:primary
;email_attribute_path =
;login_attribute_path =
;name_attribute_path =
;id_token_attribute_name =
auth_url = http://localhost:801/connect/authorize
token_url = http://localhost:801/connect/token
api_url = http://localhost:801/connect/userinfo
;teams_url =
;allowed_domains =
;team_ids =
;allowed_organizations =
;role_attribute_path =
;role_attribute_strict = false
;groups_attribute_path =
;team_ids_attribute_path =
tls_skip_verify_insecure = true
;tls_client_cert =
;tls_client_key =
;tls_client_ca =
;use_pkce = false
;auth_style =
```

This is the Firefox output with Windows Authentication in IIS:
[Grafana Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdjS5.png)

The Error in the log-File says this:

```
logger=context traceID=00000000000000000000000000000000 userId=10 orgId=1 uname=some@email3 t=2022-10-07T10:18:47.1262417+02:00 level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/login/generic_oauth status=302 remote_addr=127.0.0.1 time_ms=3 duration=3.293ms size=284 referer=http://localhost:3010/grafana/login traceID=00000000000000000000000000000000 handler=/login/:name
logger=oauth t=2022-10-07T10:18:47.3414135+02:00 level=info msg="state check" queryState=714629eaa67f449c00be02d99681bd14d05f6ce934bdcdfe86198b5ed8b0224a cookieState=714629eaa67f449c00be02d99681bd14d05f6ce934bdcdfe86198b5ed8b0224a
logger=context traceID=00000000000000000000000000000000 userId=10 orgId=1 uname=some@email3 t=2022-10-07T10:18:47.3447719+02:00 level=error msg=login.OAuthLogin(NewTransportWithCode) error="oauth2: cannot fetch token: 401 Unauthorized\nResponse: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\"> \n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"> \n<head> \n<title>IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 401.2 - Unauthorized</title> \n<style type=\"text/css\"> \n<!-- \nbody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;} \ncode{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;} \n.config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;} \npre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;} \nul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 5px;} \nul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;} \nfieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;word-break:break-all;} \n.summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;} \nlegend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;} \nlegend{color:#333333;;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-top:0px; \nfont-weight:bold;font-size:1em;} \na:link,a:visited{color:#007EFF;font-weight:bold;} \na:hover{text-decoration:none;} \nh1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;} \nh2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} \nh3{font-size:1.4em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#CC0000;} \nh4{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 5px 0; \n}#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:\"trebuchet MS\",Verdana,sans-serif; \n color:#FFF;background-color:#5C87B2; \n}#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;} \n.summary-container,.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;} \n.content-container p{margin:0 0 10px 0; \n}#details-left{width:35%;float:left;margin-right:2%; \n}#details-right{width:63%;float:left;overflow:hidden; \n}#server_version{width:96%;_height:1px;min-height:1px;margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:11px 2% 8px 2%;color:#FFFFFF; \n background-color:#5A7FA5;border-bottom:1px solid #C1CFDD;border-top:1px solid #4A6C8E;font-weight:normal; \n font-size:1em;color:#FFF;text-align:right; \n}#server_version p{margin:5px 0;} \ntable{margin:4px 0 4px 0;width:100%;border:none;} \ntd,th{vertical-align:top;padding:3px 0;text-align:left;font-weight:normal;border:none;} \nth{width:30%;text-align:right;padding-right:2%;font-weight:bold;} \nthead th{background-color:#ebebeb;width:25%; \n}#details-right th{width:20%;} \ntable tr.alt td,table tr.alt th{} \n.highlight-code{color:#CC0000;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;} \n.clear{clear:both;} \n.preferred{padding:0 5px 2px 5px;font-weight:normal;background:#006633;color:#FFF;font-size:.8em;} \n--> \n</style> \n \n</head> \n<body> \n<div id=\"content\"> \n<div class=\"content-container\"> \n  <h3>HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized</h3> \n  <h4>You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.</h4> \n</div> \n<div class=\"content-container\"> \n <fieldset><h4>Most likely causes:</h4> \n  <ul> \t<li>No authentication protocol (including anonymous) is selected in IIS.</li> \t<li>Only integrated authentication is enabled, and a client browser was used that does not support integrated authentication.</li> \t<li>Integrated authentication is enabled and the request was sent through a proxy that changed the authentication headers before they reach the Web server.</li> \t<li>The Web server is not configured for anonymous access and a required authorization header was not received.</li> \t<li>The \"configuration/system.webServer/authorization\" configuration section may be explicitly denying the user access.</li> </ul> \n </fieldset> \n</div> \n<div class=\"content-container\"> \n <fieldset><h4>Things you can try:</h4> \n  <ul> \t<li>Verify the authentication setting for the resource and then try requesting the resource using that authentication method.</li> \t<li>Verify that the client browser supports Integrated authentication.</li> \t<li>Verify that the request is not going through a proxy when Integrated authentication is used.</li> \t<li>Verify that the user is not explicitly denied access in the \"configuration/system.webServer/authorization\" configuration section.</li> \t<li>Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click <a href=\"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439\">here</a>. </li> </ul> \n </fieldset> \n</div> \n \n<div class=\"content-container\"> \n <fieldset><h4>Detailed Error Information:</h4> \n  <div id=\"details-left\"> \n   <table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"> \n    <tr class=\"alt\"><th>Module</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;IIS Web Core</td></tr> \n    <tr><th>Notification</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;AuthenticateRequest</td></tr> \n    <tr class=\"alt\"><th>Handler</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;aspNetCore</td></tr> \n    <tr><th>Error Code</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0x80070005</td></tr> \n     \n   </table> \n  </div> \n  <div id=\"details-right\"> \n   <table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"> \n    <tr class=\"alt\"><th>Requested URL</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;http://localhost:801/connect/token</td></tr> \n    <tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;F:\\repos\\Server\\Server\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0\\publish\\connect\\token</td></tr> \n    <tr class=\"alt\"><th>Logon Method</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Not yet determined</td></tr> \n    <tr><th>Logon User</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Not yet determined</td></tr> \n     \n   </table> \n   <div class=\"clear\"></div> \n  </div> \n </fieldset> \n</div> \n \n<div class=\"content-container\"> \n <fieldset><h4>More Information:</h4> \n  This error occurs when the WWW-Authenticate header sent to the Web server is not supported by the server configuration. Check the authentication method for the resource, and verify which authentication method the client used. The error occurs when the authentication methods are different. To determine which type of authentication the client is using, check the authentication settings for the client. \n  <p><a href=\"https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&amp;IIS70Error=401,2,0x80070005,17763\">View more information &raquo;</a></p> \n  <p>Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:</p> \n <ul><li>907273</li><li>253667</li></ul> \n \n </fieldset> \n</div> \n</div> \n</body> \n</html> \n"
logger=context traceID=00000000000000000000000000000000 userId=10 orgId=1 uname=some@email3 t=2022-10-07T10:18:47.3447719+02:00 level=error msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/login/generic_oauth status=500 remote_addr=127.0.0.1 time_ms=6 duration=6.0868ms size=1373 referer=http://localhost:3010/ traceID=00000000000000000000000000000000 handler=/login/:name
```

It says something about no selected authentication protocol? But Windows Authentication is selected. Why is this not passed to the header?
Maybe someone has worked on a similar problem and can get me a more clear understanding why this is happening with Grafana.

Best Regards

For more context, this is the Authorization Code where Grafana is looking for the endpoints:

```
public class AuthorizationController : Controller
{
   
    static string curUsername = "not valid";

    public void setUsername(string name)
    {
        curUsername = name;
    }

    [HttpGet("~/connect/authorize")]
    [HttpPost("~/connect/authorize")]
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Authorize()
    {
        var request = HttpContext.GetOpenIddictServerRequest() ??
                      throw new InvalidOperationException("The OpenID Connect request cannot be retrieved.");

        // Create a new claims principal
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            // 'subject' claim which is required
            new Claim(OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Subject, curUsername), //result.Principal.Identity.Name
            new Claim("some claim", "some value").SetDestinations(OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.AccessToken),
            new Claim(OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Email, "some@email3").SetDestinations(OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken)
        };

        // reset username (only set before calling from server)
        curUsername = "not valid";

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

        //ImmutableArray<string> scopes = ImmutableArray.Create(new string[] { "api", "openid"});

        // Set requested scopes (this is not done automatically)
        claimsPrincipal.SetScopes(request.GetScopes());

        // Signing in with the OpenIddict authentiction scheme trigger OpenIddict to issue a code (which can be exchanged for an access token)
        return SignIn(claimsPrincipal, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("~/connect/token")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Exchange()
    {
        var request = HttpContext.GetOpenIddictServerRequest() ??
                      throw new InvalidOperationException("The OpenID Connect request cannot be retrieved.");

        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal;

        if (request.IsClientCredentialsGrantType())
        {
            // Note: the client credentials are automatically validated by OpenIddict:
            // if client_id or client_secret are invalid, this action won't be invoked.

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            // Subject (sub) is a required field, we use the client id as the subject identifier here.
            identity.AddClaim(OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Subject, request.ClientId ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());

            // Add some claim, don't forget to add destination otherwise it won't be added to the access token.
            identity.AddClaim("some-claim", "some-value", OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.AccessToken);

            claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            claimsPrincipal.SetScopes(request.GetScopes());
        }

        else if (request.IsAuthorizationCodeGrantType())
        {
            // Retrieve the claims principal stored in the authorization code
            claimsPrincipal = (await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)).Principal;
        }

        else if (request.IsRefreshTokenGrantType())
        {
            // Retrieve the claims principal stored in the refresh token.
            claimsPrincipal = (await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)).Principal;
        }

        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The specified grant type is not supported.");
        }

        // Returning a SignInResult will ask OpenIddict to issue the appropriate access/identity tokens.
        return SignIn(claimsPrincipal, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [HttpGet("~/connect/userinfo")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Userinfo()
    {
        var claimsPrincipal = (await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)).Principal;

        return Ok(new
        {
            Name = claimsPrincipal.GetClaim(OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Subject)//,
            //Occupation = "Developer",
            //Age = 43
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: When you enable both Anonymous Authentication and Windows Authentication, only Anonymous Authentication works, as you can see from your post this is a 500 error, I suggest you use failed request tracing to see more detailed error messages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used a different approach now, I use the windows dll "avdapi32.dll" now as it can validate my username in my local intranet aswell.

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
 public static extern bool LogonUser(string username, string domain, string password, int logType, int logpv, ref IntPtr intPtr);

private void validateLogin()
{
bool isAuthenticated = false;
   IntPtr ip = IntPtr.Zero;
   isAuthenticated = LogonUser(user, "rse.intern", password, 2, 0, ref ip);
}

Comment: I'm so glad that the problem has been resolved, It is so appreciated if you can share solution as answer.